# How can I set 'master' job description for a matrix configuration job type in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

With description-setter plugin only sub-jobs, those spawned by the matrix configuration job, are having description set.
This is indeed welcome but I would like to set the main (so called master) job description as well.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "main" build description by using a *Post-build Action* > *Set build description* – you just have to tick the checkbox under *Advanced* > *Set description on multi-configuration build*:

[image: Set build description for multi-configuration project]

Note that Advanced options are *not* available for a *Build step* but only for a *Post-build Action*.